# Python package does not have setup.py,

Tags: python, pip

I would like to install this library with pip: [ikpy library](https://pypi.org/project/ikpy/). However pip gives the error below:

```
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-oYTjdr/ikpy/setup.py'
```

What I understand from the error, pip cannot find setup.py, becuase library has setup.cfg instead. I tried to upgrade pip and got a different error.

```
$ pip install --upgrade pip
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-KCnfi9/pip/setup.py", line 7
        def read(rel_path: str) -> str:
                         ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I also tried pip3:

```
$ pip3 install ikpy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 638, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

What should I do?

**Python 3.7.10, python3-pip: (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6).**

**Note:**

I solved with these commands, now it can be installed with pip3:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python3 get-pip.py 
pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
```

Comment: Did any of the answers solve your problem?

Comment: @MarioG8 Last one solved it, I set it as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ikpy library:

```
Starting with IKPy v3.1, only Python 3 is supported. 
For versions before v3.1, the library can work with both versions of Python (2.7 and 3.x).
```

You can download the latest version compatible with python 2 here:
https://github.com/Phylliade/ikpy/releases/tag/v3.0.1

note: using python 2.7 is not recommended because support for Python version 2.7 will end on January 1, 2020

Answer (score 1):

(*this message was created before the question was updated with pip3*)

It's likely that the `pip` command you use is for Python 2. Can you try with `pip3` instead?

Comment: I tried it too. but in the website they said it is pip install not pip3?

Comment: @Meric Ozcan What is Your pip and python version ? OS Linux which ?

Comment: @MericOzcan They said that because they are not expecting you to still be running a version of Python that is nearly 2 years beyond end-of-life. If you only have one version of Python then `pip` will behave as the instructions expect.

Comment: should I upgrade my python, that also gives a lot of errors :D

Comment: Python 3.7.10 python3-pip: (8.1.1-2ubuntu0.6).

Comment: @MericOzcan that should not be a problem (that version is still stable). Maybe if you explain what "errors" did you find? If they are import/syntax errors, well... you will have to change your Python ;)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Your **`Pip`**

```
 pip install --upgrade pip
```

then install **`ikpy`** Now it's should up and running ;-)

```
pip install ikpy
```

*Installed and Checked now on: Ubuntu 20.04, Pip 21.3, Python 3.8.10*